# Displaying User Input after Button Press

Tags: java, android, input, view

I'm trying to display user input after a 'submit' button has been pressed. I created the form and added code for basic validation (text, number, string length, etc.) after the submit button is pressed. This section works properly.

I want the submit button to display the input in a new view if the fields are all valid. I also want to add a feature that allows the user to edit their information (under the displayed input). I'm not sure where to start with this, mainly how to create a new view from the onClick action and how to send the variables to that view. Do I need to create a new class and XML file for this? If so, what is the best way of doing this?

Edit:

```
    public void sendFeedback(View button) {
    final EditText firstnameField = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.EditTextFirstName);
    String firstname = firstnameField.getText().toString();
    int fnlen=firstname.length();
    if (fnlen<=0){
        firstnameField.setError("Enter your first name");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add those user input fields to your normal layout and set its visibility to invisible like `android:visibility="INVISIBLE"`. It is then not visible to the user at first.

In the Code you can then set the visibility to VISIBLE again and those views appear.

```
findViewById(R.id.yourinvisibleview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge about Android dev goes, all you have to do is create a new Activity and give it the intent to start.

As for passing values to the new Class(Activity) you can use a constructor and assign the values you want to pass to private or public properties of the class(Activity)

Comment: Using the constructor for passing values does not work afaik. You have to use the intents extras to pass value. But then this is a viable solution.

Comment: not that good in Android dev, :D I am more of the iOS type, life is a lot simpler on that side of the fence

Comment: I edited the previous post with the code. Where would I add the intent action? Would it be within that function or a new one?

Answer (score 0):

For passing values to new Activity you need to use Intent .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key1,value1);
intent.putExtra(key2,value2);
```

so on..

and in your NextActivity to getData use

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(key1); // for String values
getIntent().getBooleanExtra(key2,false); // for Boolean values
```

For more about Intent Check [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: This is what I'm working on implementing now. Some tutorials mention the 'AndroidManifest.xml' file. I see it, but do I need to change it at all?

Comment: If you add a new activity that is started, then you have to add this activity in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

**1st solution:**
You use one activity, and one xml layout.
In the layout XML you add two buttons (EDIT et VALIDATE) with:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

In the SUBMIT OnClickListener, simply make all your editable EditText non-editable like this:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.date)).setKeyListener(null);
```

and make the button SUBMIT invisible, and EDIT and VALIDATE VISIBLE:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.submit)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.edit)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.validate)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In the Edit OnClickListener, you revert back:

```
KeyListener keyListener =  new KeyListener() {

                @Override
            public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int getInputType() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.date)).setKeyListener(keyListener);
    ...
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.submit)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.edit)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.validate)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And in the VALIDATE OnClickListener you do the real submit.

**2nd solution:**
You create a new activity and a new layout, just to display the values. You pass the values to the second activity by intent like this:

```
String data = "somedata";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("firstData", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

You retrieve data from the second activity like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String data = extras.getString("firstData");
```

Hope this helps.